# Do we need the [open-ended] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I saw the tag [open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) and it seemed a bit pointless to me.

The tag wiki is as follows:

> Used when the tagged puzzle is open ended to all solvers and could be "bested" at any point, if a given solver has a better solution that fulfills the askers requirements.
>
> Only use this tag if the puzzle being tagged is open ended for the community to solve, where any given answer can "best" another answer by fulfilling the requirements in a better/more efficient way. Do not attempt to use this if a question is too broad, or in place of the lateral-thinking or in place of the brainteaser tags.

I don't think we need this tag, as we don't need to be told if a puzzle is open-ended.

For instance if the question is 'What is the optimal answer?' then of course an answer can be bested. If the question is 'Find the word' then there is one answer.

**Do we need the [open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) tag?**

Comment: I say no, but I don't feel like writing up a whole answer now.

Comment: Is a downvote on the question a commentary on the **question's posting** or on the question's **proposal**?

Comment: @Rubio: The proposal. Meta votes indicate (dis)agreement.

Comment: @Rubio I agree, there are problems with how voting works on meta questions. Which is why I usually recommend that [meta-tag:discussion] questions should be phrased in an unbiased way, and if the OP has an opinion on the issue, that they post it as a self-answer instead of as part of the question. That way, the question can be upvoted for starting a useful discussion even if the answer is downvoted by people who support a different policy.

Comment: @randal'thor I wasn't arguing for either position, I was asking as I've seen both asserted.  I think the current consensus is that voting down is not commenting on the post *per se* but is expressing concurrence or dissent with the proposal, which is (to me anyway) the intuitive meaning anyway.  I'm going with that.

Answer (score 2):

Tags are not for identifying a question's type after the question is read. They're for categorizing and sorting puzzles to make browsing puzzles of a specific type easier.

If someone wants to see all of the [open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) questions, they can browse the [open-ended](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/open-ended) tag. If they don't like that style of question, they can block the tag in searches and grey out the tag on the homepage.

I find the existence of the tag useful and see no benefit to removing it.

Comment: I'm inclined to agree. I can tell whether a puzzle is about mathematics, or patterns, or "word properties", by reading it, too, but no one is proposing to remove those tags.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Says who? *(\*starts madly opening tag-removal proposals\*)*